# Modelos de múltiples argumentos sobre tibble nesteado (invoke_map tidyverse R)

Tags: r, map, tidyverse

Por un lado tengo unos **datos nesteados en R.**
Por otro lado varias funciones **nls** que quiero probar con estos datos. **Pregunto por un proceso que me permita cruzar todas las formulas nls, con muchos puntos de partida de carios argumentos, para cada una de las categorías de los datos nesteados**.

Las funciones pueden compartir argumentos o no.

Pongo un ejemplo con los datos de Iris y 2 funciones. Hay 6 combinaciones, pero insisto que busco la generalización.

Hasta dónde he llegado, he conseguido generalizar las formulas, pero no puedo tocar el tema de los argumentos de cada función.

```
iris_nested <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%  
  nest() %>%  
  ungroup()



weird_test_1 <- function(Species_data, Petal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Petal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -Petal.Width/(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width) )),
    start = list(
      Petal.Length_0 = Petal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}

weird_test_2 <- function(Species_data, Sepal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width)/Petal.Width )),
    start = list(
      Sepal.Length_0 = Sepal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}


fn_model <- function(.model, df){
  # safer to avoid non-standard evaluation
  # df %>% mutate(model = map(data, .model)) 
  df %>% 
    mutate('model'= map(data, possibly(.model, NULL)))
}

list(
  'weird_test_1' = weird_test_1,
  'weird_test_2' = weird_test_2) %>%
  map_df(fn_model, iris_nested, .id = "id_model")
```

Ninguna varianta de `invoke_map` o `exec` me ha funcionado. Se me han ocurrido soluciones con `crossing`, hacer todas las combinaciones de argumentos y problema solucionado, pero no me cuadra por no compartir argumentos algunas de las funciones.